# Is there a shortcut binding to swap caps in windows?

Tags: windows-10

We all have been in the situation where caps lock would be on and you end up with a sentence like; '`tHE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.`'.

Now i was wondering, is there some kind of shortcut or other easy way to swap the caps, to make it the regular; '`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there would an OS based way, but you need to check it tool by tool.

E.g.

- in Microsoft Word, Outlook and Power Point there is a button in "Home (format text in Outlook) - Font" to change case.
- in MS Excel you can do it by formula (`LCASE` and `UCASE`) then overwrite original values with the corrected ones.